# Best way to detect the window coordinates of a drawn line in c++ Builder

Tags: c++, bitmap, c++builder

Using moveto and lineto to draw various lines on a window canvas...

What is the simplest way to determine at run-time if an object, like a bit map or a picture control is in "contact" (same x,y coordinates) with a line(s) that had been drawn with lineto on a window canvas?

A simple example would be a ball (bitmap or picture) "contacting" a drawn border and rebounding... What is the easiest way to know if "contact" occurs between the object, picture or bitmap and any line that exists on the window?

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right you want collision detection/avoidance between circular object and line(s) while moving. There are more option to do this I know of...

1. **Vector approach**

   you need to remember all the rendered stuff in vector form too so you need list of all rendered lines, objects etc ... Then for particular object loop through all the other ones and check for collision algebraically with vector math. Like detecting intersection between bounding boxes and then with particular line/polyline/polygon or what ever.
2. **Raster approach**

   This is simpler to mplement and sometimes even faster but less acurate (only pixel precision). The idea is to clear object last position with background color. Then check all the pixels that would be rendered at new position and if no other than background color present then no colision occurs so you can render the pixels. If any non background color present then render the object on the original position again as collision occur.

   You can also check between old and new position and place the object on first non collision position so you are closer to the edge...

   This approach need fast pixel access otherwise it woul dbe too slow. Standard Canvas does not allow this without using BitBlt from GDI. Luckily  VCL GRaphics::TBitmap has `ScanLine[]` property allowing direct pixel access without any performance hit if used right. See example of it in your other question I answered:

   - [bitmap rotate using direct pixel access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44299929/2521214)

   accessing `ScanLine[y][x]` is as slow as `Pixels[x][y]` but you can store all the pointers to each line of bitmap once and then just use that instead which is the same as accessing your own 2D array. So you really need just bitmap->Height calls of `ScanLine[y]` for entire image rendering after any resize or assigment of bitmap...

   If you got tile based scene you can use this approach on tiles instead of pixels something like this:

   - [What is the best way to move an object on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29579522/2521214) but it is in asm ...
3. **Field approach**

   This one is also considered to be a vector approach but does not require collision checks. Instead each object creates repulsive force the bigger the closer you are to it which is added to the Newton/D'Alembert physics driving force. When coefficients set properly it will avoid collisions on its own. This is used also for automatic placement of items etc... for more info see:

   - [How to implement a constraint solver for 2-D geometry?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40827518/2521214)
4. **Hybrid approach**

   You can combine any of the above approaches together to better suite your needs. For example see:

   - [Path generation for non-intersecting disc movement on a plane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30639417/2521214)