# Applying a rotation to an image without sinus and cosinus

Tags: image-processing

I have read somewhere (but i do not remember where exactly) it was possible to rotate pixels of an image by applying a single matrix (just additions and multiplication).

This was done without sinus and cosinus functions.

I am wondering if i had a dream or if this is really possible...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

3x3 transform matrices are the standard abstraction in 2D graphics work. See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix . Whether this avoids sine and cosine is a bit up for debate as one typically uses those trigonometric functions to construct a rotation matrix if starting from an angle.

Comment: Do you have a C++ sample source code which does by hand the matrix calculation applying to the image ? Every code i find works with opencv so i do not see how it works in internal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no.

You apply a rotation with a matrix, as this is an affine transformation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

But if the rotation amplitude is specified by an angle, you can't avoid the use of the trigonometric functions to evaluate the coefficients.

A last remark: this is completely harmless, why worry ?

Answer (score 0):

In graphics we usually use [homogenuous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) for tasks like this. So the algo is like this:

1. **create transform matrix**

   holding all the transforms you want. For **2D** it is **3x3** homogenuous transform matrix or **2x2** rotation matrix (no translations).
2. **process all destination pixels**

   basically copy pixel from source to destination image, but the loops are looping every destination pixel (to avoid rounding holes). So let the loop goes through `(x,y)` so you just copy pixels ...

   ```
   dst[y][x] = src[y'][x']
   ```

   where:

   ```
   (x',y') = Matrix2x2 * (x,y)
   ```

   or

   ```
   (x',y',w) = Matrix3x3 * (x,y,1)
   ```

It does not matter if you use 2x2 or 3x3 matrix or hardcoded multiplication (as in example) see:

- [Rotating a square TBitmap on its center](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44299929/2521214)

but you need to use `sin,cos` for the matrix values (once per rotation). The only rotation without `sin,cos` is rotation by `90 deg` Where:

```
(x',y') = (-y,x)
```

or:

```
(x',y') = (y,-x)
```