# How to morph two images (geometric morphing) seamlessly

Tags: image, image-processing, morphing

is there a simple algorithm usable in real-time which is able to morph two images without any user inputs (so completely automatic, there is no controls points to set) ?

Basically, i don't want to morph faces nor realistic scenes, the images would actually be completely abstract and a combination of drawing patterns with regular shapes such as lines.

Thank by advance.

Comment: the easiest is tri-linear filtering ... but that is not geometric morph but linear transition between images instead.

Comment: i would like that the shape actually "morph" into others just like advanced facial morphing but without setting features points and it doesn't need to be very precise

Comment: then you should clearly state that in the OP that you want Geometric morphing. Also some sample images would be a good to share. I am no expert on the matter but I would start with interpolating scale of object to match the other one ... then based on histograms match which colors should be which at which ammound and finally  generate some paths to move them as particles into desired locations in some visually pleasing manner like [Path generation for non-intersecting disc movement on a plane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30639417/2521214)

Comment: Are the images raster or vector ? Do you know the correspondences ? What kind of morphing do you want ? Please show a sample pair.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a tool that doesn't require setting manual keypoints and is not restricted to a domain (like faces). Anyway, the images have to be similar (e.g. two faces or two cars from the same perspective). It's still a work in progress but already works great!

https://github.com/kallaballa/Poppy

[image: image morphing example]

example usage:
`poppy -o video.mkv image1.png image2.png`