# How to evenly distribute circles of different predefined sizes on the 2D surface

Tags: geometry, 2d

I have multiple thousands of differently sized circles. I need to distribute them on a plane filling empty space as tight as possible.

I am using **Unity** and **C#**, but it doesn't really matter - I can use any adviced algorythm.

Every circle have predefined `circleRadius`
Size difference between circles can be up to 10000 times.
There is no limits for plane size, but smaller is better.

Surface shape does not really matter - it can be anything two-dimensional.

Result I need is to get array of circle positions.

Please push me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you try to formalize the goal as the current formulation is a bit vague. Something like minimizing the area of the convex hull while minimizing overlap? Btw, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241893/optimal-covering-with-non-uniform-discs) looks somewhat related.

Comment: This is an instance of the Circle Packing problem. It has been studied for a long time and is hard to solve exactly. However cheap approximations can be obtained by iterative relaxation, See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339615/packing-different-sized-circles-into-rectangle-d3-js and this paper https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.5620&rep=rep1&type=pdf